# I have my QueryClient in _app.tsx setup. but it show this error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

Tags: next.js, react-query

I have a next.js 14 project and I want to use React.Query for the first time. I have my _app.tsx set up:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
console.log('apppppppp ')

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

the _app.tsx is in my app folder but I dont know why it's not working, I know there is something wrong with my _app.tsx but don't know what!

here is my folder structure

- app
  |
  |- dashboard
  |
  |-users
  |
  |-_app.tsx
  |
  |-layout.tsx
  |
  |-page.tsx

-components
|
-hooks
and the rest ...

how do I fix these !